# High value resistors in optical slave trigger? Why?

Tags: resistors

In a commercial optical trigger, for triggering flash units remotely using the on camera flash, there are two very high 30 Mohm resistors in series. Why such a circuit would need resistors so big? This trigger works well with old flash units that have an high sync voltage (up to, and sometimes in excess of, 300 V when the flash fires) or newer flash units usable with digital cameras that stay in the range of 2-6 V (but also slave triggers built from the simplest circuits that have only a photodiode and an SCR work with both if the SCR can take an high voltage)
In series with a photodiode they would be too big, as a divider they would leave nothing to the circuit to trigger the strobe... What am I missing? I cant understand their function or benefit... (and I don't have one at hand to break apart)
I attached two pictures, the first shows two slaves, same brand, same circuit, one is built-in in an hotshoe adapter the other has a plug at the back for connection to other adapters, cables or directly to the flash unit. The circuit has a photodiode, SCR, 4.7 k resistor, 400 V 0.047 capacitor, and two 30 Mohm resistors that can be seen soldered in series! I suppose the 4.7 k resistor and the capacitor are the RC to filter ambient light. The resistors are very visible in the closeup picture of the peanut slave. Triggering happens when the SCR shorts the negative rail of the flash unit and the positive center pin of the flash unit.

[image: closeup of resistors]

[image: optical slaves]

Comment: Could they be there to bleed-off the HV from the capacitor when not in use?

Comment: the capacitor in the slave? i thought the 4.7k would do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's measuring the voltage on the high voltage supply, so any loading will drain the flash battery.

300VDC through 30M\$\Omega\$ is actually quite a large current (\$10\mu\$A), and would represent several mA being continuously sucked from the flash battery when the HV converter is operating.

Comment: You mean "controlling" the voltage to NOT drain the battery?

Comment: Yes, controlling the current drawn so as to NOT drain the battery. The voltage- it can do nothing about. So they use a big R to keep the I low (and therefore the power low).

Comment: so is it in parallel with the SCR? because in series it wouldnt be able to have enough to have a trigger voltage at all... what happens with the flash units that give only 3V then?

Comment: like this? http://s14.postimg.org/nmyyew167/paral.jpg

Comment: @user36003 Yes, something like that, but the low end should go to some low-voltage circuitry rather than ground (but the current through the 60M will be about the same as if it was grounded.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. There isnt really any other circuitry at this point. Well, to be precise the two ends (positive and negative) are the hotshoe of the flash unit so thats all there is of the optical trigger. I suppose that eventually could be a place for a delay circuit in case one would want the trigger to work with the camera pre-flash (with "dumb" triggers like the optical ones the preflash is usually dealt with by the photographers with other methods)... Unless the whole photodiode and RC filter goes in there

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/pg7ddfcyd/comp.jpg

Comment: Interesting. The BPW34 is rated at only 60V, so I'm guessing it acts like a zener diode (loading the HV through 60M) that suddenly conducts more current when it sees the flash. That's AC coupled to the thyristor. Make sense?

Comment: there is the need to filter ambient light so in these things either an RC circuit or a resistor before the photodiodeon are used. BPW34 might be lower in voltage but i dont think it gets the whole sync voltage ever, yet the slave unit accomodates well both the lowest voltage flash units (like 3V) or the highest (over 300V). AC coupling you mean the diode is connected to the scr by a capacitor? thats how i drawn it, not sure its right because the resistor of the rc circuit might raise too much gate current for just one BPW34 to trigger it.

Comment: resistor might be on the negative lead as filter, before BPW34 and capacitor on positive contact of the hotshoe to avoid continuous latching, or 60Mohm resistors in parallel with SCR to keep current low to avoid latching